# Change the size of my website on Firefox?

Tags: css, html, firefox, mozilla

I am working on a website and I have been having trouble getting the whole thing to zoom out to about 80% on firefox. 
It zooms to the perfect size on internet explorer and google chrome but since I have to use -moz-transform:scale() rather than a zoom function, it not only messes with the spacing but it also removes my fixed footer. 
Currently the following options are working to get it to the right size on chrome and IE but I am wondering if there is another property for firefox which I can use to zoom. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So you're looking for `zoom` for Firefox?

Comment: You [asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828894/zoom-a-whole-website-on-firefox) 9 hours ago. Why did you delete it and start again?

Comment: And why do you want to zoom it anyway? If you are zooming it everywhere, all the time, then just make everything smaller to begin with.

Comment: @Quentin Really dude? Because I need an answer. And it not that easy to just start all over again